# Setting the tab spacing/size visualization for a JavaFX TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX 8 and specifically the TextArea control.  In that control I can enter free form text including "tab" characters.  When I enter a tab, the data is spaced in units of 8 characters.  For example.  In the following, the `!` character is where I enter a tab:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
!       Data here
ABC!    Data here
!!              Data Here
```

My puzzle is how to change the tab spacing/sizing for the visual so that instead of the tab size being 8 characters it will only be 4 characters.

To further illustrate, here is an actual screen shot showing tabs in my text area:

[image]

I want to leave the data as containing tab characters and not replace tabs with spaces.

This Stack Exchange question does not apply as it talks exclusively about changing tabs to space:

[JavaFX TextArea: how to set tabulation width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773483/javafx-textarea-how-to-set-tabulation-width)

Comment: Why not use the solution you found? You can modify it to post a tab of 4 characters. Or do you need to use `\t`?

Comment: @eckig My desire is to leave the tab characters in the source.  For example, I may wish to load the String from an external source, modify it and write it back.  I don't want to "replace" the \t (tab character) with spaces.  Instead, I want to be able to specify (only for TextArea visualization) the tab position.  I am also getting the impression that in the TextArea, it isn't just that tabs are replaced with 8 spaces ... it seems that a tab visualizes data at the NEXT multiple of 8 spaces.  I want to change "8" to "4" (for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to grunge through the source code of JavaFX to see if I could find an answer and, although I am not an expert in examining such a large amount of code, I seem to have found that the answer is that the tab size is hard-coded to be 8 characters!!

I found the source file called:

`com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.java`

which has a method called `getTabAdvance` which returns a fixed value of "8".  See the following:

[image]

This is most disappointing to me but it is what it is.

Comment: Good research. I share your disappointment - I don't know what kind of animal thinks 8 spaces is reasonable for a tab.

Comment: A `setTabSize` Method has since been added to `com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout` & its Interface `com.sun.javafx.scene.text.TextLayout` but how does this relate to `javafx.scene.control.TextArea` ?

Comment: @DaveTheDane When I implemented variable tab sizes for Text and TextFlow the intention was to support rich editors like RichTextFX.  You could file an enhancement request to get the same CSS options and setTabSize for javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl ... but it looks like CSS for Text will do. See my answer.

Comment: @Scott I was going to add an Enhancement Request but can't figure out how to register?! I see there is some mention of a Census?...

Answer (score 2):

After the implementation of [JDK-8130738](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8130738) in JavaFX 14, you can now change the advance of a tab character to any multiple of 'spaceAdvance'.  `Text` and `TextFlow` now have a `tabSize` property and the CSS supports `-fx-tab-size`

Since [`TextAreaSkin`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/b0f2521219efc1b0d0c45088736d5105712bc2c9/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextAreaSkin.java#L1038) implements the `TextArea` using `Text` nodes, you can change the tab size of the `TextArea` with CSS.

Example:

```
package example.stackoverflow;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaTabs extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    private File cssFile;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        var slider = new Slider(1, 50, 8);
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, old, newValue) -> {
            try {
                updateTabSize(newValue.intValue());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Can't write CSS file.");
            }
        });
        var ta = new TextArea("This is a test\n\tafter a tab\n\t1\t2\n");
        ta.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced"));
        var vbox = new VBox(8,new HBox(8,new Label("Tab size:"),slider),ta);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        scene = new Scene(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TextArea Tab Experiment");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateTabSize(int spaces) throws IOException {
        File oldFile = cssFile;
        cssFile = File.createTempFile("textareatabs", ".css");
        cssFile.deleteOnExit();
        Files.writeString(cssFile.toPath(), """
                Text {
                  -fx-tab-size: %d;
                }
                """.formatted(spaces), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        String confStyleSheet = cssFile.toURI().toString();
        scene.getStylesheets().setAll(confStyleSheet);
        if (oldFile != null) {
            oldFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does JDK-8130738 have any relevance to the subject of this question, TextArea?

Comment: @DaveTheDane It looks like the TextAreaSkin implements the control with Text nodes.  Using CSS you should be able to set the tab size.  https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/b0f2521219efc1b0d0c45088736d5105712bc2c9/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextAreaSkin.java#L1038

Comment: @Scott, thanks for that. I found adding a monospace font made it even clearer. Something like `ta.setFont(Font.font("Consolas", 12));`

Comment: @DaveTheDane I've updated the example code. Feel free to give it a vote if you think it answers the question. ;-)

Comment: @Scott I was holding back on that as its still somewhat of a workaround, but a prettty good one at that so I've given you my vote. P.S. like the Slider you just added. Is there any way of passing in CSS without writing a work file?

Comment: @DaveTheDanen I believe in JavaFX 17 onwards there have been changes to allow base-64 encoded data in URLs https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8267554  I’ve left my code as-is to remain compatible with JavaFX 14.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243543/discussion-between-swpalmer-and-dave-the-dane).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of Scotts Proggy adapted to use the new JavaFX 17 Data-URI's:

P.S. I use the Azul Zulu openJDK 17 JavaFX Runtime Bundle
You can get that here:
https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#download-openjdk

```
package example.stackoverflow;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.util.Base64;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaTabs extends Application {

    private static final String CSS_TABSIZE_N  = "Text {-fx-tab-size: %d}";

    private static final char   TAB            = '\t';
    private static final char   NEWLINE        = '\n';

    private static final String TABBED_TEXT    = "This is a test" + NEWLINE + TAB + "after a tab" + NEWLINE + TAB + "1" + TAB + "2";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        final var sliderLabel = new Label("Tab size:");

        final var slider      = new Slider(1, 50, 8);
        ;         slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, old, newValue) -> updateTabSize(newValue.intValue()));

        final var textArea = new TextArea(TABBED_TEXT);
        ;         textArea.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced"));

        final var vBox = new VBox(8, new HBox(8, sliderLabel, slider), textArea);
        ;         vBox.setPadding(new Insets(8));

        scene = new Scene(vBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TextArea Tab Experiment");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateTabSize(final int tabSize) {

        final var styleText   = CSS_TABSIZE_N.formatted(tabSize);
        final var styleBase64 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(styleText.getBytes(UTF_8));
        final var url         = "data:text/css;charset=UTF-8;base64," + styleBase64;

        System.out.println(styleText + TAB + " -> " + url);

        scene.getStylesheets().setAll(url);
    }
}
```